# What does "binary volume" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> The connectivity of the pore network in the SiC/SiCN material is assumed to be very high since pyrolysis leads to a shrinkage of the matrix therefore leading to cracks throughout the matrix. In order to prove this assumption, a labeling of the objects in a smaller region of interest (1 x 1 x 0.5) mm3 of the **binary volume** is performed.

What does "binary volume" mean?

I can't find this notion at all. Maybe someone has assumptions what it can be?

Comment: Can you provide some context?

Comment: The connectivity of the pore network in the SiC/SiCN material is assumed to be very high since pyrolysis leads to a shrinkage of the matrix therefore leading to cracks througout the matrix. In order to prove this assumption, a labelling of the objects in a
 smaller region of interest (1 x 1 x 0.5) mm3 of the binary volume is performed.

Comment: I would also like to ask about the second sentence as I've not really got what the author wanted to say.

Comment: Here is my assumption: The author is interested in the real-world physical object shrinking. They label various points on the computational model of the object. They then run a simulation of whatever the relevant real-world processes are. They then check to see if the labelled points *in the computational model* are closer together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A binary volume is a 3D representation of something using binary digits. In this case, it sounds like a computational model of a real-world physical object, very common in neuroscience, materials science, engineering, and many other fields. Below I show you a (badly drawn) binary representation of a sphere in 2D. If you imagine this in 3D (so with 125 bits instead of 25), that would be a binary volume of the sphere.

```
00100
01110
01110
00100
```